# Code worked at first but after running it twice its producing error

Tags: algorithm, tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, image-classification

I was trying to do model accuracy and perfomance of the CNN binary classification algorithm.
I was comapring the following models

1. Resnet
2. efficient Net?
3. Mobile net
4. Google net
5. Vgg
6. dense net
   My code  worked for 3 of these algorithms and later on if I am trying to run the code it is producing the following error I dont understand why.
   I dont have a gpu, So i am using cpu.

```
Found 639 images belonging to 2 classes.
Found 160 images belonging to 2 classes.
2023-06-12 17:13:05.196457: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/process_util.cc:146] Creating new thread pool with default inter op setting: 2. Tune using inter_op_parallelism_threads for best performance.
2023-06-12 17:13:10.474854: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/executor.cc:1197] [/device:CPU:0] (DEBUG INFO) Executor start aborting (this does not indicate an error and you can ignore this message): INVALID_ARGUMENT: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder/_0' with dtype int32
     [[{{node Placeholder/_0}}]]
Epoch 1/10
# **OMP: Error #34: System unable to allocate necessary resources for OMP thread:**
OMP: System error #11: Resource temporarily unavailable
OMP: Hint Try decreasing the value of OMP_NUM_THREADS.


Fatal Python error: Aborted


Main thread:
Thread 0x00007ff74babb500 (most recent call first):
  File "/home/pavani/anaconda3/envs/tf_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py", line 52 in quick_execute
  File "/home/pavani/anaconda3/envs/tf_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/polymorphic_function/monomorphic_function.py", line 381 in call
  File "/home/pavani/anaconda3/envs/tf_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/polymorphic_function/monomorphic_function.py", line 1757 in _call_flat
  File "/home/pavani/anaconda3/envs/tf_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/polymorphic_function/tracing_compiler.py", line 143 in __call__
  File "/home/pavani/anaconda3/envs/tf_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/polymorphic_function/polymorphic_function.py", line 959 in _call
  File "/home/pavani/anaconda3/envs/tf_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/polymorphic_function/polymorphic_function.py", line 894 in __call__
  File "/home/pavani/anaconda3/envs/tf_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/traceback_utils.py", line 150 in error_handler
  File "/home/pavani/anaconda3/envs/tf_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1685 in fit
  File "/home/pavani/anaconda3/envs/tf_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 65 in error_handler
  File "/home/pavani/Desktop/Model_accuracy_somehow_it_worked.py", line 84 in <module>
  File "/home/pavani/anaconda3/envs/tf_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/spyder_kernels/py3compat.py", line 356 in compat_exec
  File "/home/pavani/anaconda3/envs/tf_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/spyder_kernels/customize/spydercustomize.py", line 473 in exec_code
  File "/home/pavani/anaconda3/envs/tf_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/spyder_kernels/customize/spydercustomize.py", line 615 in _exec_file
  File "/home/pavani/anaconda3/envs/tf_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/spyder_kernels/customize/spydercustomize.py", line 528 in runfile
  File "/tmp/ipykernel_415739/3624669338.py", line 1 in <module>


Restarting kernel..
```

I tried Using

```
config = tf.compat.v1.ConfigProto(
    intra_op_parallelism_threads=1,
    inter_op_parallelism_threads=1
)
tf.compat.v1.keras.backend.set_session(tf.compat.v1.Session(config=config))
```

but still the same error and when I am printing the results

```
results_df = results_df.append({
       'Model': pretrained_model.name,
       'Accuracy': accuracy,
       'Training Time': training_time,
       'Trainable Parameters': trainable_count
   }, ignore_index=True)


# Save the DataFrame to an Excel file
results_df.to_excel('model_results_3.xlsx', index=False)
```

only one model output is printed dont know why